# panda save and read excel in loop

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop where I call a function in which I loop to read an excel, then write and save it. But at the end I only the last result is stored.
As a simple example

```
for i in range(3):    
   callfunc(i)

callfunc(i)
    panda open excel
     for j in range(10:13:1)
        write in excel(i,j) in new sheet
    save excel
```

As final result i only get (3,10) (3, 11) (3,12).
It seems when re-opening the excel in the `callfunc` the excel doesn't get saved but the original excel is kept and I dont get why.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Let's use separate sheet_name:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"~\Desktop\excelData\data.xlsx"

book = load_workbook(path)
for i in range(3):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
    writer.book = book

    df = pd.DataFrame(x3)

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = '{}__sheet'.format(i))

    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```